# Origine dell'espressione "Avere il pallino per/di..."

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Mi viene la curiosità di sapere l'origine dell'espressione "avere il pallino per/di..."

Il significato lo conosco - prendo dalla [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pallino_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/):

> **a.** [idea fissa: *ha il pallino dell'ordine*] ≈ assillo, chiodo (fisso),
> fissazione, mania, ossessione. ‖ smania.
>
> **b.** [propensione naturale per
> una disciplina, per un'arte e sim., con la prep. di: *avere il pallino della
> musica*] ≈ attitudine [...]

Personalmente, ho sentito più spesso adoperarla nell'accezione **b** e mi chiedo da dove arrivi il modo di dire.

Per l'accezione **a** ho trovato [su questo sito](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/linguamadre/articolo.php?art=120) questa spiegazione:

> Con molta probabilità il modo di dire si collega all'uso dei giocatori
> di bocce che per vincere la partita cercano di far accostare il più
> possibile le bocce al pallino.
> Di qui, appunto, il probabile significato di pallino come idea fissa
> verso la quale tutto converge.

Che mi convince solo fino a un certo punto e convince ancora meno se cerco di collegarla all'accezione **b** per cui vi chiedo se c'è una spiegazione alternativa o migliore.

Nota che nella stessa pagina della Treccani viene citata l'espressione familiare

> attitudine (a), (fam.) ***bernoccolo***, disposizione (per), inclinazione (per), predisposizione (a).

Che "pallino" sia una sostituzione di "bernoccolo" ?

Answer (score 1):

Non sembra esserci una chiara connessione tra pallino e bernoccolo nell’ accezione di inclinazione/passione verso qualcosa.

Altre fonti citano il gioco delle bocce come possibile origine del metaforico “pallino” mentre l’origine del bernoccolo sembra avere la seguente origine:

> Il termine viene da una scienza di moda ai primi del 1800, la frenologia, fondata dal medico tedesco F.J.Gall e presto spogliata di ogni credibilità scentifica. Secondo tale teoria le facoltà mentali erano localizzate in punti ben determinati della corteccia cerebrale, e lo sviluppo di una particolare facoltà portava all'ispessimento della parte corrispondente, formando una bozza nella scatola cranica. Gall aveva identificato ventisette facoltà diverse, riconducibili ad altrettanti bernoccoli.

[Dizionari.Corriere.it](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/bernoccolo.shtml?refresh_ce)

Comment: La spiegazione sul 'bernoccolo' è davvero perfetta - la frenologia calza a pennello. Ancora mi sfugge il collegamento tra avvicinarsi al pallino delle bocce e attitudine/propensione/passione verso qualcosa :/

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi -  i giocatori di bocce si fissano sul pallino, hanno come scopo quello di avvicinarsi il più possibile al pallino. In senso metaforico il pallino diventa una fissa o un target. Penso questo.